# Is there any special meaning to $(MAKE) in a makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to read a makefile and it uses the variable $(MAKE). I can't see where this is getting defined. Is it a special variable of some sort? We're using GNU make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an automatically defined variable. It is usually used to call make into subdirectories. More info in [GNU make manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable).